# How to pass json parameters for Jenkins using CURL?

Tags: curl, jenkins, dsl, json

I'm trying to build a job by passing JSON parameter for Jenkins through Linux CLI. But I'm not able to pass the parameters in JSON. I have used -g to turn off globbing. Still the issue persists. Any help would be appreciated.

```
curl -X POST -u username:password -g JENKINS_URL/job/Bulk_Job/buildWithParameters?serviceBranchJson="{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}"}
```

Error message

```
Processing provided DSL script
{key1:value1,key2:value2}}
groovy.json.JsonException: expecting '}' or ',' but got current char 'k' with an int value of 107

The current character read is 'k' with an int value of 107
expecting '}' or ',' but got current char 'k' with an int value of 107
line number 1
index number 1
{key1:value1,key2:value2}}
```

Code snippet

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def serviceBranchJson = serviceBranchJson

println(serviceBranchJson)

Map servicesMap = new JsonSlurper().parseText(serviceBranchJson)
```

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 0):

First: the number of left and right curly brackets does not match (one left, two right).
Second: When you type parameters in quotes on command line the shell understands it like "do not touch what's inside" but passes it to the process without quotes. See the result of this example:

```
echo "{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}"
```

So I'd try to enclose the whole expression in single quotes or escape the single quotes, something like this:

```
echo '{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}'
```

or this:

```
echo "{\"key1\":\"value1\",\"key2\":\"value2\"}"
```